# Colección de expresiones usadas para decir "faltar a clase"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, expresiones

Si me preguntaran cuál es la expresión que más variedades lingüísticas tiene, yo diría sin lugar a dudas que las usadas para denotar el *faltar a clase a propósito para dedicarse a otros menesteres*. La RAE admite con más o menos este significado el término **[hacer novillos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qg8UiDY)**, que a mí particularmente me recuerda a los tebeos de Zipi y Zape. A partir de aquí, las variedades ya no dependen simplemente del país, sino también de la región y casi me atrevería a decir que del pueblo.

Hay un par de artículos ([aquí](http://www.blogolengua.com/2010/09/hacer-pinta-rata-vaca.html) y [aquí](https://hablandodepalabras.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/hacer-novillos-origen-y-expresiones-afines/)) que he encontrando con un compendio de estas expresiones. Sin embargo, ambos sitúan en Argentina, Paraguay y Uruguay una expresión que en Sevilla usábamos mucho cuando yo iba al colegio: **[hacer rabona](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UzFnvHc)**. En cambio, la expresión que ubican en Andalucía en el segundo artículo (**hacerse una piarda**) no me suena de absolutamente nada ("piarda" no está ni en el diccionario). Sí me suenan otras como **[hacer pellas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SOeuRby)** (de Madrid) o **hacer campana**.

Así pues, ¿qué expresiones recordáis o sabéis que se usan actualmente para este concepto? ¿Estáis de acuerdo con los artículos o tenéis vuestra propia adaptación del término?

Comment: ¿En Madrid no se decía hace un tiempo *irse de toros*, o estoy recordando mal?

Comment: Sería buenísimo que gente de cada uno de los países validara las siguientes que indica [hablandodepalabras](https://hablandodepalabras.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/hacer-novillos-origen-y-expresiones-afines/): _En Ecuador se dice echar o hacerse la pera; en Argentina, Paraguay y Uruguay, hacerse la rabona; también en Argentina, hacerse la rata o hacerse la yuta; en México, irse de pinta; en Puerto Rico, comer jobos; en Honduras y El Salvador, irse de capiura; en Perú, hacer la vaca; en Chile, hacer la cimarra; en Venezuela, jubilarse de clases; en Colombia, capar clase._

Comment: En [este hilo de twitter](https://twitter.com/EnsaladaPalabra/status/1401941060960538631) hablan de esto.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Respuesta en modo *community wiki*, siéntete libre de añadir aquí tus propias opciones.

## Argentina

- Hacerse la rabona
- Hacerse la rata / ratearse
- Hacerse la yuta / cuca (Noroeste)

## Bolivia

- Chuñearse una clase

## Chile

- Capear clases
- Hacer la cimarra
- Hacer la chancha

## Colombia

- Capar clases
- Mamar clases

## Cuba

- Fugarse del turno (un turno de clases)

## España

#### Aragón

- Hacer pirola
- Hacer pellas
- Hacer borota

#### Cartagena

- Fugarse la clase

#### Cataluña

- Hacer campana
- Fumarse la clase
- Saltarse la clase

#### Ibiza

- Hacer salera

#### Madrid

- Hacer pellas
- Irse de pellas

#### Málaga

- Hacerse una piarda

#### País Vasco

- Hacer pira

#### Sevilla

- Hacer rabona
- Saltarse la clase

#### Valladolid

- Pirarse la clase

Sobre el mapa (sacado [de Twitter](https://twitter.com/pavlo_ar02/status/1194652245578731520)):

[image]

## México

- Irse de pinta
- Echarse la brincona
- Pintar venado

## Perú

- Hacerse la vaca
- Tirarse la pera

## Sin localización encontrada:

- [Pintar venado](https://www.wordmagicsoft.com/diccionario/es-en/pintar%20venado.php)

Comment: No sé si es sólo en Cataluña o extendido a toda España: fumarse la clase (fumarse matemáticas, por ejemplo).

Comment: @guillem, yo tenía entendido que en Cataluña se usaba el "hacer campana". He editado la respuesta, si estoy equivocado y no se usa esa expresión avísame para que lo corrija.

Comment: @Diego, sí, sí, hacer campana es indiscutible. Lo de fumarse una hora o una clase era un aporte extra que no sé dónde clasificar.

Comment: He oído "hacer la rata" en Andalucía.

Comment: "Hacer campana" es usado en Cataluña, igual que "saltar la clase" que también lo usamos en [catalán](http://dlc.iec.cat/results.asp?txtEntrada=saltar).

Comment: En Ibiza (no sé si en otros lados) usamos "hacer salera"

Comment: @guillem Vivo en Catalunya (barcelona), y nunca habia escuchado lo de fumarse X clase. En que zona se usa?

Comment: @Aimnox, en Barcelona y área metropolitana. «Si comemos rápido y nos fumamos matemáticas nos da tiempo a ir al cine».

Comment: @guillem, vaya, siempre use "y nos saltamos mates" para eso. Bueno de saber!

Comment: @Aimnox cabo de encontrar un hilo de WR, pero sigue sin estar claro si es extensivo a España o sólo a alguna región: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fumar-la-clase.677245/

Comment: @guillem puedes añadir el término como usado en Barcelona, y si alguien lo reconoce como usado en otro sitio, que lo añada también a esa otra región.

Comment: Me he tomado la libertad de añadir la que propone @AlexBcn también.

Comment: Bolivia: Chuñearse (de chuño: papa deshidratada, alimento milenario de la cultura andina). Hoy no fui a clase de ingles = Me chuñeé ingles. Ignoro totalmente el origen de la expresión.

Comment: "Pintar venado" - pero no sé en qué zonas se utiliza

Comment: En http://lingua2.cc.sophia.ac.jp/varilex/php-atlas/lista3.php?page=1&search_fd1=D074 y siguientes recogen 79 ·registros", cada uno con su mapa de distribución ...

Comment: Parece que en Madrid también se usa "picar". Véase en [este vídeo, segundo 40"](https://twitter.com/quiquepeinado/status/1441107755759144961)